# Member reference base type 'char' is not a structure or union in C++

Tags: c++

Can someone help me to debug this problem in C++? 
I want it to loop if the user want to enter once again, but the error keeps on showing up.

```
void typeA(){
    int j;
    char dec;
    do{
        cout << "Enter Month: ";
        cin >> month[j];
        cout << "Enter Date: ";
        cin >> date[j];
        cout << "Enter Time in Hour: ";
        cin >> aHours[j];
        cout << "Enter Time in Minutes: ";
        cin >> aMins[j];
        cout << "Enter Time Out Hour: ";
        cin >> aHours[j];
        cout << "Enter Time Out Minutes: ";
        cin >> aMins[j];

        cout << "Enter Again?: [y/n]";
        cin >> dec;

    }while(!dec.compare('y'));
    cout << "Exit";

}
```

Comment: Hi Raven! Could you please paste absolutely all of your code, even `#include` statements that might not seem important. (If you don't have any `#include` statements, that would be your problem right there.)

Comment: `!dec.compare('y')` char has no `operator.` because it is not a union/struct as the error says. I dont know what you were attempting to do with that. most likely dec != 'y' ?

Comment: Your problem can be reduced to `char dec; dec.compare;`.

Comment: `char` is a basic type. In C++, basic types can't have methods. You should simply compare `dec != 'y'`

Comment: @ArthurTacca No #include will fix trying to call a non-existant `compare` method on a `char`

Comment: @Borgleader But it would've helped me paste the code and run it through a compiler and see where the error was without having to pick through it myself. At the moment it will probably complain about unknown symbol `cout`. (Pasting the exact error message including the line number would probably have sufficed too.) Plus it is good practice to let new people know about.

Comment: I'm trying to compare the decision of the user. I think my statement if incorrect can you help me to correct it?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @Raven As the other people stated, char does not have compare (or any other method). Are you mistaking it for string? Simply write `dec != 'y'` as already stated. != and == are also perfectly fine on string, by the way.

Comment: @Raven If you think your statement is correct, you should start with [a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). C++ is not Java or Python and don't try to draw parallels. `char` has no methods. You can't call a method on `char` variable.

Comment: You cannot "debug" compiler errors, you just need to fix them

Comment: Thank You everyone. You helped me fix my problem :)

Comment: @Raven `j` is uninitialized and doesn't change between iterations of the loop.        `month`, `date`, `aHours`, `aMins`, `aHours` and `aMins` are undefined. Are you using global variables? If so, stop it.

Comment: okay sir. ill take not all your responses. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `==` operator to check if two [fundamental types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) are equal or not, because the fundamental types in C++ can't have methods.

```
void typeA(){
    int j;
    char dec;
    do{
        cout << "Enter Month: ";
        cin >> month[j];
        cout << "Enter Date: ";
        cin >> date[j];
        cout << "Enter Time in Hour: ";
        cin >> aHours[j];
        cout << "Enter Time in Minutes: ";
        cin >> aMins[j];
        cout << "Enter Time Out Hour: ";
        cin >> aHours[j];
        cout << "Enter Time Out Minutes: ";
        cin >> aMins[j];

        cout << "Enter Again?: [y/n]";
        cin >> dec;

    }while(dec == 'y');
    cout << "Exit";

}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `operator==` for `char`.

Comment: @Swordfish Why does that work?

Comment: it works tho. i dont know why but yes it works.

Comment: @Mohit new your explanation is not misleading anymore.

Comment: @Swordfish Sorry, But I mean that.

Comment: @Raven it was just about using the term `operator==` which is a different thing than `==` in C++.

Comment: More correct term for C++ is fundamental types, not primitive. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types